# What are safe area padding values on different iOS devices?

Tags: ios

I have found a lot of resources detailing how to design iOS apps so that all interactive elements fall in the safe areas, but I haven't been able to find documentation with actual pixel values on different devices. Where can I find a resource with this information?

Comment: I need to emulate it for development because relevant method in Unity game engine doesn't return device-specific values in the editor: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-safeArea.html

Comment: SafeArea insets in unity work just fine.. they return it in pixels (as a safe area rectangle) instead of offsets from the left and right..

Comment: @Brandon it works just fine on a device. It does not emulate device values in the editor.

Comment: Check out: https://connect.unity.com/p/updating-your-gui-for-the-iphone-x-and-other-notched-devices  It has a section on "Editor Simulation"..

Comment: @Brandon I am asking this question exactly in order to put in the values I so I can emulate a device in the manner which is very similar to what they're describing.

Comment: The article shows that you don't need EVERY single safe area inset for every single device to emulate in the editor.. it emulates the most common safe-area inset and emulates it. All others are literally only 1% larger at most.  If iOS is causing you problems with insets.. how do you plan to deal with Android which now has insets as well? IE: Pixel 3, samsung, etc.. Run the code in the simulator like suggested and write down all the safe area insets yourself for every device and orientation?

Answer (score 1):

Ask for the main view's [`safeAreaInsets`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891103-safeareainsets) to get the numbers you want (and override [`safeAreaInsetsDidChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891104-safeareainsetsdidchange) to be notified when you need to ask for it again).

If you need a list of safe area insets in advance without calling that method, make a little project that calls that method and run it on every simulator. But you will have to do that for many configurations, because the safe area insets depend upon things like the status bar visibility, navigation bar visibility, toolbar visibility, orientation, device type, and so on.

Comment: I don't think that it's a good solution, because I'm not sure that result is not changed because of other invariants, like version of operating system. I would like to find the official documentation on this matter rather than base my experiments on faulty assumptions.